# Multiple POM files in a single maven project for Maintainability & readability

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a single Java project (Maven based) where default POM (`pom.xml`) is there.
it contains some third party dependencies that are included in locally under `/lib` folder.

For the sake of maintainability and readability i want to split them and keep my specific dependencies in various files OR pom files.
How is that possible?

Please note i this is not going to be aggregated or parent project just single project.

Comment: Those 'third party dependencies' are available on public maven repository?

Comment: What is the "them" that you want to split? The dependencies? I fail to see how having dependencies in different places (instead of just one) would help maintainability. Maybe you have good reason for that, but impossible to tell from the succinct description in your question. As of now, it is pretty unclear to me what is the problem you are trying to address, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Some dependencies are available and most of them are not. More over i want to split POM into TWO. i can import one into default pom and keep growing second one.

Comment: What do you mean by `and most of them are not. .` ..? Furthermore if you have deps which are only inside your company start using a repository manager and deploy them into it and afterwards just use them as usual dependencies...that's it...

Comment: you are right we can create repository to manage it, the question is about Spliting POM file into multiple POM's and using one as default pom and others are included in the main POM in order to keep separate poms for various dependencies.